# Why i am getting the same output for both oranges ans abc arrys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, javascript-objects

```
//ORANGES=[5,-6]/// T=11

function countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges) {

  var abc = oranges;
  abc.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    arr[index] = item + t
  });
  console.log(abc)
  console.log(oranges)


}

//OUTPUT FOR BOTH [16,5] HOW ????///
```

Comment: all of them are refering same array

Comment: because after `var abc=oranges;`, both reference the same array.

Comment: what I want to do is I want to store the values of oranges array into some other array in which I can do the operation and my oranges array remain the same. HOW TO DO THAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@uminder` said, In `var abc = orange` line `abc` is referring the `orange` array. So both references are same.

You can do `var abc = [...orange]` instead of that.

```
function countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges) {

  var abc = [...oranges];

  abc.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    arr[index] = item + t
  });
  console.log(abc)
  console.log(oranges)


}
```

**OR**,

```
function countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges) {

  var abc = [];
  oranges.forEach(function(item, index) {
    abc[index] = item + t
  });
  console.log(abc)
  console.log(oranges)


}
```